# Which one is most secure REST or SOAP?

Tags: rest-api, soap-api

Hi I am new for integration. Please can any one suggest me which is most secure REST or SOAP. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Both are equal from security stand point. Rest is newer and lighter. Most of new Integration are base on Rest API.